# angular app doesn't bootstrap and doesn't throw any errors

Tags: angularjs

This isn't th first time this has happened but angular simply doesn't bootstrap the application and throws no errors to the console.

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["applicationModule"]);
    });
```

Other times I've been able to get out of the situation because I knew what caused it, but now I'm not sure why and angular is not telling me a thing.

I just get an empty ng-view and applicationModule.run() doesn't get called.

I tried something silly like wrapping all of angular.js in a try/catch block but it doesn't output anything.

Comment: could you share your more code?

Comment: since you are manually bootstrapping, you are not using the ng-app directive, right?

Comment: can you create a minimal plunker where it happens?

Comment: are you sure you are adding your all the components inside `applicationModule`?